# Calculate SUM based on CR - DR Trans Type

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have following result set

```
BranchCode | AccountNo | TransType | TransAmount
    ABC123 |    001    |   CR      |    1000
    ABC123 |    002    |   CR      |    5000
    ABC123 |    001    |   CR      |    3000
    ABC123 |    001    |   DR      |    2000
    ABC567 |    001    |   CR      |    8000
    ABC567 |    002    |   CR      |    7000
    ABC123 |    002    |   DR      |    1000
    ABC567 |    002    |   DR      |    9000
```

I want to have output like below

```
BranchCode | AccountNo | BalanceType | BalanceAmount_CR| BalanceAmount_DR
  ABC123   |    001    |     CR      |   2000          |     0.00
  ABC123   |    002    |     CR      |   4000          |     0.00
  ABC567   |    001    |     CR      |   8000          |     0.00 
  ABC567   |    002    |     DR      |   0.00          |     2000
```

I have tried multiple ways including PIVOT, LEFT JOIN USING SAME TABLE but every time my result set is different.

One of the way I tried

```
SELECT  
 BranchCode 
,AccountNo
,(CASE 
        WHEN TransType='CR' THEN (SUM(TransAmount)) END)  AS BalanceAmount_CR
,(CASE 
        WHEN TransType='DR' THEN (SUM(TransAmount)) END)  AS BalanceAmount_DR
 
FROM TransTable 
GROUP BY  BranchCode,AccountNo,TransType
```

When I add TransType in group by it creates new row and calculate sum, I just want single row for each type of transaction

P.S. This is not any kind of school project, I have a complex table structure but have simplified my problem to understand easily.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: updated .pls check

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Some explanation would help, e.g. how 1000 + 3000 = 2000 for `ABC123`/`001` `BalanceAmount_CR` and why `BalanceAmount_DR` is zero for that output row. Do you really want to `group by` `TransType`? Where does `BalanceType` come from?

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved by self. Just posting answer if someone wants to know.

```
SELECT  
 BranchCode 
,AccountNo
,SUM(CASE 
        WHEN TransType='CR' THEN (TransAmount) END)  AS BalanceAmount_CR
,SUM(CASE 
        WHEN TransType='DR' THEN (TransAmount) END)  AS BalanceAmount_DR
 
FROM TransTable 
GROUP BY  BranchCode,AccountNo
```

I just moved SUM function.

Comment: That's completely not what you asked in your expected result

Comment: The `BalanceType` column of the result is missing. Clearly not what the OP requested, as _you_ should know.

Answer (score 1):

**It looks like you don't actually want to group by `TransType`. What you seem to be doing is calculating a total balance `CR-DR` and then splitting out positive and negatives into different columns.**

You can do this with a derived table:

```sql
SELECT 
 BranchCode 
,AccountNo
,CASE WHEN BalanceAmount < 0 THEN 'DR' ELSE 'CR' END AS BalanceType
,CASE WHEN BalanceAmount >= 0 THEN BalanceAmount ELSE 0 END AS BalanceAmount_CR
,CASE WHEN BalanceAmount < 0 THEN -BalanceAmount ELSE 0 END AS BalanceAmount_DR
FROM (
    SELECT  
     BranchCode 
    ,AccountNo
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN TransType='CR' THEN TransAmount END) -
      SUM(CASE WHEN TransType='DR' THEN TransAmount END) AS BalanceAmount
    FROM TransTable 
    GROUP BY  BranchCode,AccountNo
) AS t
```

You could also put it into a CTE, or use a bunch of `CASE` expressions in the `SELECT`.